# Difference between Openrack vs Openrack v2

Tags: mount, standards, rack

The Open compute project has  different types of projects for open rack.

The following is the types (family) of OpenRack mentioned in open compute contributions.

1. `OpenRack v2`
2. `OpenRack`
3. `OpenRack v1`

Following is the link. I have filtered for rack.

https://www.opencompute.org/contributions?refinementList%5Bproject%5D%5B0%5D=Rack%20%26%20Power&page=1&configure%5BfacetFilters%5D%5B0%5D=archived%3Afalse&sortBy=contributions_by_accept_date_desc

So, it can be understood that `OpenRack v1` is older spec than `OpenRack v2` from name itself.

But where does `OpenRack` stand? Can we consider it later than v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Where does only OpenRack stand? Can we consider it later than v2?

No.

> **RACK Standards**
>
> A rack developed by any supplier that is certified as OCP compliant
> provides a consistent interface between for the IT gear it supports.
> The latest version of the standard is below:
>
> ```
> Available Files           Version     Submit Date     Contributor     License
> Open Rack Specification   2.2         OCT 19          Open Rack       OCPHL-P
> ```

Source: [Open Rack/SpecsAndDesigns - OpenCompute](https://www.opencompute.org/wiki/Open_Rack/SpecsAndDesigns#RACK_Standards)

Comment: okk. so not later than v2, why it has been in different family then? I am unable to get that you have answered my main problem statement though.